# How to iterate over 1 <= i < j <= n elements in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops

So I am trying to do a for loop over the upper triangle part of a matrix, so I only want the elements 1 <= i < j <= n. And I tried it out in R as follows:

```
for(i in 1:n-1) {
    for(j in i+1:n) {
        ...
    } 
}
```

But instead of iterating over 1 <= i < j <= n these for loops go over the elements i + 1 <= j <= i + n, 1 <= i < n.

I'm new to R, so I don't understand what is happening. Could someone give me a hint how to do it correctly?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked out the baseR `upper.tri()` function already?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: you're making a common error with order of operations. Set `n <- 5` and use the console to compare `1:n-1` with `1:(n -1)` (and similarly for the `+` version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i in seq(1, n - 1)) {
  for(j in seq(i + 1, n)) {
     ...
  } 
}
```

alternatively

```
for(i in 1:(n - 1)) {
  for(j in (i + 1):n) {
     ...
  } 
}
```

The issue is that R understands `i+1:n` as `i + (1:n)`